# Has anyone tried running Drupal 9 under Windows Datacenter 2022 IIS?

Tags: iis

We are running Drupal 9 happily under IIS and Windows Datacenter 2019 under Azure. Microsoft have released Windows Datacenter 2022 so I thought I should try to migrate to that platform. It opens find, but none of the links work, for example https://site/login gives a Page not found error. I have URL Rewrite installed and the same rules as in other environments; one is supposed to rewrite ^(.*)$ to index.php with the Append query string set.

I suspect that URL Rewrite isn't playing ball, but I can't be sure. Has anyone else any experience?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of hunting around, and testing with another index.php file, I determined that Drupal was a red herring. the URL Rewrite module was not working. Uninstalling, rebooting the server and reinstalling it cured the problem.